# How can I show an Ad popup after search form is submitted?

Tags: webforms, search

How can I place an Advertisement after clicking the search button and before showing the search results?
can anyone help me with this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

you could try a custom [search-results.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-results.tpl.php/7) to create a [JS](https://www.drupal.org/node/304255) overlay while the results are being rendered